# Do the app goes inactive in Google Play Store, if I publish an update with different app title?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have published an App in Google Play Store with title "AppName-beta". And it goes live on Play Store. Now I want to update its title to "AppName", So the question is that if I publish new Update, will my currently active app (AppName-beta) hide from Play Store immediately or after the update success?

Comment: If you publish it on production and you create a release on production it will update your old version by the newer version. Same in beta, App publish on beta will be overwrite by release of new app version release in beta. Beta version can only be seen by user who register as beta tester

Comment: I have Published it to production but now i want to change the app name with the new release.. So, I jus want to know if I do this, will it immediately remove my currently active app in store until the update is reviewed/published ?

Comment: Sure you can update your app title for already published app on play store. But make sure package name and alias name should be same. When your new apk will live, it will reflect to end users on play store with new name without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update app with different `app title`, then app will not inactive on Google Play Store. You must **take care of copy rights in app name** or app with same name already exists on Google Play Store. 
If you only want to update app title on Play Store, then no need of upload new release. 
If there is any important update in new Release then you can upload it with new `App Title`.

Answer (score 0):

let say you have uploaded an apk in play store, and it is live now and some user install that apk, and now if you again update the apk in google play store console, then it will update in play store less than 24hr but the users who have already install that app, has to update the app again to get the updated thing.